# Azure custom DNS server not being refreshed

Tags: azure, dns, refresh, domaincontroller

I am setting up custom AD Domain controller + DNS VM on my Azure VNet. Initially the VNet was pointing to on-prem DNS server. After I provision the new AD DNS VM I rightly see that it is pointing to the on-prem DNS server which it inferred from the VNet settings. I then installed the AD DNS components on the VM. Now I change the VNet to point to the new AD DNS VM's IP. However even after I reboot the new AD DNS server I still see it pointing to the on-prem server. I can in no way change this setting by updating either VNet or NIC settings. Is this due to some special constraints that come with how ADDC DNS configuration? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you change the DNS server to point to the new DNS VM's private IP? What's the DNS server in the network interface level on the Azure portal? Try to reboot the VM and run `ipconfig/flushdns` to clear DNS cache, then verify it again.

Comment: i think vnet\nic settings do no override whatever you manually set on the vm

Comment: AD DNS installation has the habit of prompting people to set P Config to static even thought its not required.  I assume you did not do that, correct?

Comment: Really appreciate you quick responses. I am pretty sure we did ipconfig/flushdns. I am waiting for confirmation from our AD support team on this. Also we have in our process not to ever update anything manually from with VM. Again awaiting confirmation on that. Will keep you posted as soon as I get it. One question - In Azure we can assign multiple DNS server records. Is there any significance on how we order these DNS entries? How does one of these get assigned to a VM and how do we know at one point of time which DNS server a VM is using?

Comment: I checked with the team and they have confirmed what I mentioned last week. It seems the only option now is to set the intended DNS configuration on the VNet and rebuild the VMs again so they get fixed to these set IPs. I understand in future if the DNS IPs change again then they might not be reflected on these VMs. But I think these AD DNS VMs need only to point to the on-prem DNS IPs and the to themselves for the DNS resolution and this we are ensuring by pre-entering these values at the VNet level which the new instantiations will pick up. We should be fine if these IPs stay fixed in future

Comment: As an update, the problem got resolved - yes the support team did find there was hard coding in the DNS server settings. After removing it its taking the VNet DNS settings. I assume they were not careful enough to notice that. As of now as part of the process, after AD role installation we are putting in a check to remove any hard coded DNS server settings from the VM that might have been created as part of the installation